# multi equation - optimization problem ( known answer, need step by step solution)

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization

I am new to this forum and I do not have a math background. However, I need to find the solution to the following. The answers are already known, but I do not know how to find these answers, I appreciate your help. (I need to find out how the parameters which are listed at the end such as x1, x2, etc are calculated)

[image: Check the math formula in here]

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. It is usual to type out your question rather than simply providing an image (I know this can be time consuming but it is worth it as more people will help with your problem). See [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for help with MathJax formatting. It is also helpful to explain exactly which steps you are stuck on, rather than asking people to explain every step of a calculation

Comment: Hello Lioness99a. I wish I could explain this. This is a part of Fuzzy AHP process, I already figured out some other parts. But for this equation, I have no knowledge at all that what is this called or how it can be solved. I don't know where to start :(

Comment: This is a quite complex optimation problem ! Confusing is that $x_1$ and $x_2$ do not appear in the function we want to minimize.

Comment: Thank you Peter, at least at this point I know this is called optimization problem. This does not even look like a linear equation that I could find x, y, z ..., I am fairly new to this. Even if I could ignore the part that says Minimize I cannot solve the part that says Subject to. I cannot find the values even with ignoring the minimization condition.